# How do you use headroom.js with Bootstrap 3 navbar?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I found this JavaScript widget http://wicky.nillia.ms/headroom.js/ and I want to use it in a web application using Bootstrap 3. It  doesn't seem to be working. Any suggestion or example what I should do?

I'm currently using navbar-fixed-top on the navbar. I tried with and without it and it is still not working. I can see the headroom.js classes applied to the header but there is no effect in the UI elements.

---

**Resolved**

You need to add this style.

```
<style type="text/css">
.headroom {position: fixed;top: 0;left: 0;right: 0;transition: all .2s ease-in-out;}
.headroom--unpinned {top: -100px;}
.headroom--pinned {top: 0;}
</style>
```

Source: http://codeasp.net/blogs/raghav_khunger/microsoft-net/2314/how-to-use-headroom-js

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem. You need to add this style.

```
<style type="text/css">
.headroom {position: fixed;top: 0;left: 0;right: 0;transition: all .2s ease-in-out;}
.headroom--unpinned {top: -100px;}
.headroom--pinned {top: 0;}
</style>
```

Source: http://codeasp.net/blogs/raghav_khunger/microsoft-net/2314/how-to-use-headroom-js

Thanks [Fox Genki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1402896/fox-genki) for the source link.

Comment: Your welcome, please accept your answer to help other person that have the same question.

Comment: Has anyone found a good way to compensate for the collapse subnav/submenu? When the navbar retracts, only the navbar is hidden and not the submenu. I tried setting the subnav opacity to zero when the "slideup" class is applied to hack around it, but it's still pretty clunky.

Comment: @jp_inc in the headroom.js parameters you can hook in events that do things when its pinned and unpinned. Perhaps you could use that event to trigger whatever it is that bootstrap uses to show and hide the dropdowns.

Comment: @jp_inc you can use this code so the submenu will hide automatically.
    `$('.nav a').click(function(){
      $(".navbar-toggle").trigger( "click" );
      });`

Answer (score 5):

Try this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").headroom();
</script>
```

Source : http://codeasp.net/blogs/raghav_khunger/microsoft-net/2314/how-to-use-headroom-js

Demo : http://fiddle.jshell.net/raghav_khunger/d7QQ8/2/show/light/

Comment: The source gave me the answer. You need to add some additional style to make it working. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The styles in the accepted answer aren't required to get headroom.js to work w/ Twitter Bootstrap 3. Simply following the [instructions](http://wicky.nillia.ms/headroom.js/) will work with navbar-fixed-top. The main thing is that you assign styles to these classes, otherwise nothing appears to happen.

```
.headroom--pinned {
    display: block;
}
.headroom--unpinned {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the above steps but it wasn't working until i added "!important" to the styles.So it became this:
`<style type="text/css">
.headroom {position: fixed;top: 0;left: 0;right: 0;transition: all .2s ease-in-out !important;}
.headroom--unpinned {top: -100px !important;}
.headroom--pinned {top: 0 !important;}
</style>`
 its working now :)

Comment: I am not very good with CSS but I think your other styling overrides .headroom.