# How to get headroom.js working / step-by-step

Tags: javascript, html, css, headroom.js

I really like the headroom.js but I just can not get it working. Some kind of step-by-step instruction would be great.
So here is what I did so far...

1. I downloaded the [git repro](https://github.com/WickyNilliams/headroom.js)
2. Included the scripts to my html file right before my closing body tag

`<script  type="text/javascript" src="js/headroom/Headroom.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="js/headroom/jQuery.headroom.js"></script>`

3. Added following css to my css files

   `.headroom {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   }
   .headroom--unpinned {top: -100px;}
   .headroom--pinned {top: 0;}`
4. Added the headroom script at the very and even after the scripts links in point number 2

   `<script>
   (function() {
   var header = new Headroom(document.querySelector("#header"), {
       tolerance: 5,
       offset : 205,
       classes: {
         initial: "animated",
         pinned: "slideDown",
         unpinned: "slideUp"
       }
   });
   header.init();
   }());
   </script>`
5. Added the necessary ids and classes to my header HTML element
   `<header id="header" class="header header--fixed hide-from-print" role="banner"><my navigation stuff goes in there></header>`

But I do not get it working somehow. I do not see any classes applied when scrolling nor anything else. Does anyone know the wrong part?

I would be so greatful,..

thanks in advance

Comment: is there nobody to give me a helping hand? I dont get it working with this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648451/how-do-you-use-headroom-js-with-bootstrap-3-navbar)

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar setup to what you have above in an older site using version **0.7.0** of **Headroom.js** and **jQuery.headroom.js**. These were the files in the `/dist` directory of that version. Headroom.js was working as expected. I then tried the latest version **0.9.3** using the files from the `/src` directory (as the `/dist` is no longer included since **v0.8.0**) and it did not add any classes to the selected element, and there were no errors thrown (everything loaded correctly, but no joy). Now, I'm a self reported novice, thus I'm certain there is a good explanation as to why this was a breaking change for my setup.

Answer (score 1):

Don't download it from Github, because you will need to build it first before using.

1. Go to the developer website http://wicky.nillia.ms/headroom.js/
2. Click on "Production" red button to download.
3. Then follow rest of the documentation.